# Sunspot Solr search parameter "with" not working with strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I'm developing a Ruby on Rails application using Sunspot Solr as an indexer.
The thing is i try to use the parameter of the search with :, using strings and it doesn't seem to work. If i pass an int it works fine. Anyone knows how to do it with strings (if it's possible)?

An example of the search i want to do is:

```
@search = Sunspot.search(Record) do
     fulltext params[:query]
     with :checked, "Checked"
end
```

:checked is an attribute of the table Record and it validates if a record is checked so it can't be edited.

PD: I'm doing it this way because MySQL doesn't accept booleans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out!

It turns out strings are a little more delicate, so you have to use:

with(:checked).equal_to("any_value")

For more information see:

https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Scoping-by-attribute-fields